# how to print true or false depending on addition in python?

Tags: python, printing, addition

I am a bit confused on how to get this to print either true or false, for example, you have 4 of Xobject which have a value of 2 each and you have 5 of Yobject which have a value of 5 each.

you have to see if 3 xobject and 2 yobject fit into 15. this should print false as you are not able to break the objects in half or count all of them together.

as in you **can not** do 3(2) + 2(5) = 16, which is larger than 15 but involves you adding the objects together which is not allowed as they are meant to be two completely different things

Comment: You can add objects of different class. You need to define your `__add__` accordingly. See [this](https://dbader.org/blog/python-dunder-methods).

Answer (score 0):

ok so here's one way of doing it:

```
 x = 2 #value of each x object
 y = 5 #value of each y object

 xObjects = int(input('How many x objects:'))
 yObjects = int(input('How many y objects:'))


 if ((xObjects * x) + (yObjects * y)) == 15:
    print("True")
 else:
    print("False")
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but I am not able to count them all together, they have to be two completely separate ways of adding them up, for example to if you had 2 of Yobject and 3 of xobject, and you were trying to get to 11, you would need to use 2 yobjects and 1 xboject

Comment: I think your question is not very clear then, because you have stated xobject to have a value of 2, and yobject a value of 5, and if you want to get 11? that's not 2yobjects and 1 xobjects, but more like 1 yobject and 3 xobject?either way will you be using a user input functionality?